# Transform dataframe to a certain JSON format

Tags: json, r

I need to go from this dataframe:

```
> dat
   Code Project      Status
1   A01     Pr1 In progress
2   A02     Pr1    Complete
3   A03     Pr2    Complete
4   A04     Pr1    Complete
5   A05     Pr1 In progress
6   A06     Pr3    Complete
7   A07     Pr3 In progress
8   A08     Pr3    Complete
9   A09     Pr2    Complete
10  A10     Pr2 In progress
```

to this JSON object:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Complete",
    "values": [
      {
        "label": "Pr1",
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "label": "Pr2",
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "label": "Pr3",
        "value": 2
      }
    ],
    "color": "#440154FF"
  },
  {
    "key": "In progress",
    "values": [
      {
        "label": "Pr1",
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "label": "Pr2",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "label": "Pr3",
        "value": 1
      }
    ],
    "color": "#FDE725FF"
  }
]
```

In this JSON object, `value` is a count, and `color` is a color for each level of `Status`; the colors must be distinct.

I have a solution with `data.table`:

```
dat <- read.table(
  text = "Code,Project,Status
A01,Pr1,In progress
A02,Pr1,Complete
A03,Pr2,Complete
A04,Pr1,Complete
A05,Pr1,In progress
A06,Pr3,Complete
A07,Pr3,In progress
A08,Pr3,Complete
A09,Pr2,Complete
A10,Pr2,In progress", sep = ",", header = TRUE
)

originalNames <- names(dat)
xName <- "Project"
byName <- "Status"

names(dat)[match(xName, originalNames)] <- "...X"

library(data.table)
library(viridisLite)

DT0 <- as.data.table(dat)
DT1 <- DT0[, .(count = .N), keyby = c("...X", byName)]
DT2 <- DT1[
  , .(values = list(data.table(label = `...X`, value = `count`))), by = byName
]
names(DT2)[1L] <- "key"
DT2[, `:=`(color = viridis(nrow(DT2)))]

jsonlite::toJSON(DT2, pretty = TRUE)
```

Does it sound good and would you have something better to propose?